# Email link to local windows resource with space

Tags: email, outlook, hyperlink, samba, netbios

How do I encode a link in a plaintext email to a local network resource with a space in it.

For instance this will only highlight up to the word "file" but not "file name"

```
\\SERVER\share\file name
```

Yet if I do this

```
\\SERVER\share\file+name
or
\\SERVER\share\file%20name
```

Then Windows Explorer does not recognize the path correctly.

I realize the different mail clients will handle things differently, but is there a standard way to encode a local network resource?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the resource with angle brackets <\server\share>
Works for me in 2007
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could do it as an actual URL, like file://\SERVER\share/file+name.

Comment: I tried file://\\SERVER\share which works fine, but the "file+name" part still doesn't work.  Windows says "Window cannot find ..., Check the spelling " etc...

Comment: %20 also has the same results as +